# how to check if Leverage browser caching is enabled

Tags: css, .htaccess, caching, browser, browser-cache

I Was wondering if there exist an method using which i can check if an website has Leverage browser caching enabled or not and if enabled then for how much time
example an css file link like `http://foo.com/foo.css` or an image link `http://foo.com/foo.img`
now how to know if Leverage browser caching is enabled in them and its configuration.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [pageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) From Google to help you search for the Laverage browser caching.

This website: http://gtmetrix.com/leverage-browser-caching.html can create a insight of all the performance you can gain by optimizing your website.

Answer (score 0):

Check if browser caching is enabled (and expiration) https://www.giftofspeed.com/cache-checker/

- also, GTmetrix may warn "Leverage browser caching for the following cacheable resources:" for .SVG files (ignore if so)